# Book layout Contents, Chapter, Section,

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, formatting, chapters, book-design

my goal is to get new style of Table of Contents, new style of Chapter and new style of section. I there is one more: how to change itemize native symbol for a black square?

Table of Contents: text on the left side in the middle of two lines. And there is a big white space non normal one.
[image]

Chapter: number of chapter in a roman in a black box on the line above the chapter name, Name of chapter on right side, another line under name of Chapter

[image]

Section: I want to add a black square at the begining of each section name.
[image]
I appreciate that
thank You

Comment: With respect to the section formatting, you want to add a black square at the beginning (before the title), but should this square replace the section number or do you want to keeo the numbering?

Comment: Should the elements (the chapter titles, the entries in the ToC) be boldfaced or not?

Comment: I want to have a section number. In table of contents the chapters should be boldfaced, but section no. In text both should by blodfaced.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the packages [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) for the titles of the sectional units, and [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) for the entries in the ToC; a little example producing the layout for chapters and sections, and the redefinition of the label for `itemize` to use a square (feel free to adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}

% chapter tiltes formatting
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}\hspace*{0.5em}\colorbox{black}{%
    \parbox[c][1.2cm][c]{1cm}{%
      \centering\textcolor{white}  {\Huge\thechapter}}}}
  {-1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{.7ex}\filleft\MakeUppercase{#1}}
  [\vspace{.2ex}\titlerule]
% chapter tiltes spacing
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{80pt}

% section tiltes formatting
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\MySecSquare\ \thesection}{1em}{#1}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\MySecSquare}{1em}{#1}

% formatting for chapter entries in ToC  
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [1.5em]{}
  {\sffamily\bfseries\contentslabel{1.5em}}
  {\hspace*{-1.5em}}
  {\hfill\sffamily\bfseries\contentspage}
% formatting for section entries in ToC  
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]{}
  {\sffamily\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\sffamily\contentspage}

% Square to be used in itemize
\newcommand\MySquare{%
  \leavevmode\hbox to 1.2ex{\hss\vrule height .9ex width .7ex depth -.2ex\hss}}
% Square to be used in section titles
\newcommand\MySecSquare{%
  \leavevmode\hbox to 1.2ex{\hss\vrule height 1.3ex width 1.1ex depth -.2ex\hss}}

% First level of itemize uses a square
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\MySquare}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{itemize}
\section{Test Section One Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter Three}

\end{document}
```

An image of the ToC showing the requested formatting for the entries, and an image of the first numbered chapter, showing the desired chapter titles formatting, the use of a black square in `itemize` and the section titles formatting:

[image]

[image]

There's a little detail that deserves some thought: the black box used to typeset the chapter number; in the code above I used a `\parbox` of fixed width (I chose `1cm`) and this will be insufficient for "large" roman numerals (such as VIII), One option is to increase the width of the `\parbox`, but then small numerals (such as I) might not look good inside a too wide box. Another option is to have a default width of, say `1cm`, and let the widht of the `\parbox` increase just for those numbers requiring more spacing; here's now the code implementing this idea:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}

\newlength\BoxWd
\setlength\BoxWd{1cm}
\newlength\Aux

% chapter tiltes formatting
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}%
    \settowidth\Aux{\textcolor{white}{\Huge\thechapter}}
    \ifnum\Aux>\BoxWd
      \setlength\BoxWd{\Aux}
    \else\fi
    \hspace*{0.5em}\colorbox{black}{%
    \parbox[c][1.2cm][c]{\BoxWd}{%
      \centering\textcolor{white}{\Huge\thechapter}}}}
  {-1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{.7ex}\filleft\MakeUppercase{#1}}
  [\vspace{.2ex}\titlerule]
% chapter tiltes spacing
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{80pt}

% section tiltes formatting
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\MySecSquare\ \thesection}{1em}{#1}

% formatting for chapter entries in ToC  
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [1.5em]{}
  {\sffamily\bfseries\contentslabel{1.5em}}
  {\hspace*{-1.5em}}
  {\hfill\sffamily\bfseries\contentspage}
% formatting for section entries in ToC  
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]{}
  {\sffamily\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\sffamily\contentspage}

% Square to be used in itemize
\newcommand\MySquare{%
  \leavevmode\hbox to 1.2ex{\hss\vrule height .9ex width .7ex depth -.2ex\hss}}
% Square to be used in section titles
\newcommand\MySecSquare{%
  \leavevmode\hbox to 1.2ex{\hss\vrule height 1.3ex width 1.1ex depth -.2ex\hss}}

% First level of itemize uses a square
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\MySquare}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\setcounter{chapter}{17}% just for the example
\chapter{Test Chapter Eighteen}

\end{document}
```

An image of the titles for chapters I and XVIII:

[image]

[image]

Comment: WOW! I love it. There is only one thing: How to do a big skip between Contents and Chapter included in Contents, as it is showed on the first picture.

Comment: Itemize dosen't work as it should have.

Comment: @DanielMiliński right now I am busy, but in a few hours I will update my answer with the (easy) modifications requested. In the meantime I have two questions 1) The vertical skip between the title and the text should only apply to the Table of Contents or should it apply to all chapters? 2) You said that the `itemize` doesn't work as you expected, but you requested a square and my code produces a square... can you please explain in detail what is not working?

Comment: First of all Thank You.Ad.1.--Indeed want vertical skip between chapters, so If You could write it down, i would be grateful. Ad.2 after generation a .pdf itemize look's normal. I have put the label in the itemize environment in text (\begin{itemize}\item[\MySquare] First Item,\item[\MySquare] Second) and it is working. Oh, and there is one more (if that isn't too much),in polish language we use dot's next to chapters number.For example:1. First Chapter in ToC,but only next to arabic's numbers.How to do that?

Comment: How I can Thank You?It is great amount of work You have done for my

Comment: @DanielMiliński You're welcome! I'm glad I could help. I've updated my answer introducing some modifications; in particular, the ToC entries and the spacing after chapter are now incorporated; I also included a new approach to redefine the symbol used in `itemize` (this new approach doen't require additional packages and should work). Please let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: It is perfect! Now itemize work just fine. It look's great.

Comment: @DanielMiliński I corrected the position of the square in sections. I also added a new variation automatically modifying the width of the black box used for the chapter numbers.

Comment: another questions: How to get ToC widther? How to add dots next to the chapters, and how to put on odd sides name of current chapter but without a chapter -- just number of the chapter and name of it, and on the even side title of a book. Both withouth \MakeUppercase. Last one: next to the \section*{} there is no black square -- how to add it to this enviroment?

Comment: more spacing in a parbox is very usefull.

Comment: @DanielMiliński I just added to my example the code for unnumbered sections to also have the black square. Regarding your other requirements, I think it's best to open a new question with them; you could add a link to this question so that people would know that it is a follow-up question.