# ToC width, small \MakeUppercase font in a header, dots next to chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, header-footer

1. How to get ToC widther?
   1a. How to get ToC higher? [more space under the chapter, before a next chapter]
2. How to add dots next to the chapters?
3. How to put on odd sides name of current chapter but without a chapter -- just number of the chapter and name of it on the right side [on left -- page number], and on the even side title of a book [on right -- page number]. Both with \MakeUppercase but with a smaller font.

   ```
    \documentclass[openany, 10pt]{book}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    \usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}

    \newlength\BoxWd
    \setlength\BoxWd{1cm}
    \newlength\Aux

    % chapter tiltes formatting
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
       {\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE}
       {\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}%
         \settowidth\Aux{\textcolor{white}{\Huge\thechapter}}
         \ifnum\Aux>\BoxWd
          \setlength\BoxWd{\Aux}
         \else\fi
         \hspace*{0.5em}\colorbox{black}{%
         \parbox[c][1.2cm][c]{\BoxWd}{%
          \centering\textcolor{white}{\Huge\thechapter}}}}
      {-1ex}
      {\titlerule\vspace{.7ex}\filleft\MakeUppercase{#1}}
      [\vspace{.2ex}\titlerule]
      % chapter tiltes spacing
      \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{80pt}

      % section tiltes formatting
      \titleformat{\section}
        {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\MySecSquare\ \thesection}{1em}{#1}

      % formatting for chapter entries in ToC  
      \titlecontents{chapter}
       [1.5em]{}
       {\sffamily\bfseries\contentslabel{1.5em}}
       {\hspace*{-1.5em}}
       {\hfill\sffamily\bfseries\contentspage}
      % formatting for section entries in ToC  
      \titlecontents{section}
       [3.8em]{}
       {\sffamily\contentslabel{2.3em}}
       {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
       {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\sffamily\contentspage}

      % Square to be used in itemize
      \newcommand\MySquare{%
        \leavevmode\hbox to 1.2ex{\hss\vrule height .9ex width .7ex depth -.2ex\hss}}
      % Square to be used in section titles
      \newcommand\MySecSquare{%
      \leavevmode\hbox to 1.2ex{\hss\vrule height 1.3ex width 1.1ex depth -.2ex\hss}}

      % First level of itemize uses a square
      \renewcommand\labelitemi{\MySquare}

      \begin{document}

      \tableofcontents

      \chapter{Test Chapter 1}
       \section{Test Section 1}
       \section{Test Section 2}
       \section*{Test Section 3}
      \chapter{Test Chapter 2}
      \chapter{Test Chapter 3}
      \chapter{Test Chapter 4}
      \chapter{Test Chapter 5}
      \chapter{Test Chapter 6}
      \chapter{Test Chapter 7}
      \chapter{Test Chapter 8}
      \chapter{Test Chapter 9}

      \end{document}
   ```

This is a follow-up question: [Book layout Contents, Chapter, Section,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66559/book-layout-contents-chapter-section)

Comment: REegarding your first requirement, do you want to change the text width only for the ToC or for all of the document?

Comment: Why did you open a bounty?

Comment: "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possible solution; I used the `titleps` package to define a new page style with the required settings (please make sure to have an updated LaTeX system and that `titleps` is installed). The modification to add dots for chapter entries in the ToC was accomplished using `\titlerule*` (from the `titletoc` package).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\BoxWd
\setlength\BoxWd{1cm}
\newlength\Aux

% chapter tiltes formatting
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}%
    \settowidth\Aux{\textcolor{white}{\Huge\thechapter}}
    \ifnum\Aux>\BoxWd
      \setlength\BoxWd{\Aux}
    \else\fi
    \hspace*{0.5em}\colorbox{black}{%
    \parbox[c][1.2cm][c]{\BoxWd}{%
      \centering\textcolor{white}{\Huge\thechapter}}}}
  {-1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{.7ex}\filleft\MakeUppercase{#1}}
  [\vspace{.2ex}\titlerule]
% chapter tiltes spacing
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{80pt}

% section tiltes formatting
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\MySecSquare\ \thesection}{1em}{#1}

% formatting for chapter entries in ToC  
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [1.5em]{}
  {\sffamily\bfseries\contentslabel{1.5em}}
  {\hspace*{-1.5em}}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\sffamily\bfseries\contentspage}
% formatting for section entries in ToC  
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]{}
  {\sffamily\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\sffamily\contentspage}

% Square to be used in itemize
\newcommand\MySquare{%
  \leavevmode\hbox to 1.2ex{\hss\vrule height .9ex width .7ex depth -.2ex\hss}}
% Square to be used in section titles
\newcommand\MySecSquare{%
  \leavevmode\hbox to 1.2ex{\hss\vrule height 1.3ex width 1.1ex depth -.2ex\hss}}

% First level of itemize uses a square
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\MySquare}

% Command to store the book title
\newcommand\MyTitle{The Title of The Book}

% definition of new page style
\newpagestyle{mystyle}[\footnotesize]{
\sethead[\MakeUppercase{\MyTitle}][][\thepage]
{\thepage}{}{\thechapter\ \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\lipsum[1-20]
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}

\end{document}
```

Some images illustrating the requested modifications:

The ToC:

[image]

The top part of some pages showing the headers:

[image]

[image]

In case the titleps package is not availabel, the desired page style can also be produced using the fancyhdr package; using this package, you need to replace the lines

```
\usepackage{titleps}

% definition of new page style
\newpagestyle{mystyle}[\footnotesize]{
\sethead[\MakeUppercase{\MyTitle}][][\thepage]
{\thepage}{}{\thechapter\ \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
```

with

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% definition of new page style
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[EL]{\footnotesize\MakeUppercase{\MyTitle}}
\fancyhead[OR]{\footnotesize\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
```

in the example code above.

Comment: I can not install new packages. So I can not tell You is it evrything all right. [no titleps] http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66855/tex-live-problem-with-install-ubntu-bash-new-packages

Comment: @DanielMiliński OK; I've updated my answer with another solution for the page style using `fancyhdr` instead of `titleps`. You still haven't answered my question regarding the width: do you want to increase the text width just for the ToC or for the entire document?

Comment: @DanielMiliński Thank you very much for the bounty!