# TeX Live -- problem with install [Ubuntu, bash]; new packages

Tags: packages, installing, texlive, ubuntu

I don't know how to install new packages. I've tried to install texLive [I have installed sudo apt-get install texlive-full -- which went correct, but I can not install Tex Live], but after install TeX Live dosent'respond. I write tlmgr, and I get response 'no comand 'tlmgr' ' I have read documentation, but now I am confused even more.

So:

1. how to install TeX Live on bash [correctly]
2. Say I want to install packages: `xcoffins.sty`

   - what kind of file download from CTAN?
   - where put them?
   - how to make them work with TeXstudio?
3. How to keep TeX Live updating new packages

How to do this Step-by-Step.

I feel like I have tried absolutly every way, but not the correct one.

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu. Broadly, if you install the 'managed' TeX system, there is no `tlmgr` and you get what Ubuntu provides. On the other hand, you can install TeX Live yourself 'outside' of the system manager, then do your own thing.

Comment: Marco Daniel I have instaled newest version of TeX Live. What now?

Comment: Now that you installed TeX Live, you have the `tlmgr` tool. Run `tlmgr option repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet` on a terminal to change the repository and then run `tlmgr update --self --all` to update `tlmgr` itself and your installation; you need to run this last command when you want to update your installation. [Here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html) you can find a tutorial on `tlmgr`. To install packages which are not included in the TeX Live distribution, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/3954.

Comment: liveTex is in a newest version. But I can not run tlmgr. What is wrong? or How to do that?

Comment: I used: http://support.rstudio.org/help/kb/faq/installing-tex-live-2012-for-ubuntu-1204 to install TexLive. It was corret instalation. But there is no tlmgr, or it is not working, or I can not turn it on. 'Beam me up, Scott' It's madness down here.

Comment: I suspect you have the Ubuntu version of TL12, it does NOT include tlmgr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually this is a further comment on corentin's answer, but it exceeds 600 characters.

---

Since http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ is an Apache directory listing you can try downloading packages with wget. For example if you want to download `l3experimental` where `xcoffins` is a subfolder you can invoke wget like

```
wget --cut-dir=4 -np -R "index.html*" -nH -P ~/texmf -r http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/
```

or

```
wget --cut-dir=6 -np -R "index.html*" -P ~/texmf/tex/latex -r http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/
```

this.

- `-P ~/dir/in/home/directory/` specifies the local directory where `wget` should put your files.
- `-nH` tells `wget` that you don't want to create directories named after the host i.e. `~/texmf/www.tug.org/*/*/` looks not so nice and latex won't find anything under `~/texmf/www.tug.org`. But you can omit `-nH` and change the local directory to `-P ~/textmf/tex/latex`. Then you have a seperate directory tree that latex also searches.
- whereby `--cut-dir=x` means that you don't want to create the first x folders of the uri in your local directory (you want to create `~/texmf/tex/latex/l3experimental/` or `~/texmf/tex/latex/www.tug.org/l3experimental/` instead of `~/textmf/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental`).
- `-R` instructs `wget` to exclude all files beginning with `index.html`.
- `-r` is for recursive fetch
- the argument of `-P` is the directory where you want to save all those things
- `-np` excludes all parent directories of `l3experimental` (of course you can find a more detailed description in the manual pages of `wget`)

but generally be careful if you download things with `wget` recursively it could mess up a whole directory tree. I would recommend you to first download the files in a temporary directory (for example with `-P ~/texmftemporary`) where you can examine the downloaded directory tree.

Since latex also searches recursively for packages in `~/texmf/tex/latex` you don't have to bother if `xcoffins` is a subfolder of any other folder/folders.

Of course you can redefine things further if you write a little `bash`, `perl` or `whatever` script that is based on the above command.

Maybe this helps you!?

Answer (score 4):

It is my understanding that you tried to install the official `TeXLive` packages through Ubuntu repositories by running sudo `apt-get install texlive-full` in Ubuntu 12.04 but hit a wall at some point. The links provided by @JosephWright is a good start. The answers and links there were what helped me when I had the same problem with TexLive in Ubuntu 12.04 two months ago.

I don't know if the TeXLive in the Ubuntu repositories is now updated to 2012. Last time I checked (2 months ago) it was still TeXlive 2009. So if you have already installed TeXLive by running `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` you may want to uninstall it again by running `sudo apt-get remove texlive-full` in your terminal then follow the online installation procedure [here](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).

- Specifically, you download `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` and extract to your desired folder, say at ~/Downloads.
- In your terminal type `cd` to the extracted folder and run `sudo perl install-tl`. Type `I` to install. You may accept default values. The installer will then download and install TeXLive from the nearest `ctan` mirror near you. Take note of your installation path.
- After the download has finished, run `gedit ~/.profile` or alternatively, open your file browser and go to `home`, hit `ctrl+h` and run `.profile.` At the end of the file, write the path to your texmf directory. For 32-bit computers, the default is:

`PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux:$PATH; export PATH`

`MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH`

`INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH`

For 64-bit computers, the default is:

`PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH`

`MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH`

`INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH`

Again, check the location of your `texmf` carefully to avoid problems later on. Save the file and close it. To check if your installation is successful, run `tex` in your terminal. It should show something like:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012)
**
```

If it doesn't work, try rebooting.

**To install `texstudio`, run the following commands:**

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blahota/texstudio`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install texstudio --ignore-depends=texlive`

The `--ignore-depends` option will cause `dpkg` to ignore the dependency check.

After installation, you may have to configure texstudio but if there is no problem with the installation, it should work fine.

If all went well, you will find that `xcoffins.sty` is also installed in your tex directory. Also, you can now update using `tlmgr`. And texstudio will also work out just fine.

Comment: With `sudo apt-get install texstudio --ignore-depends=texlive` you intended to replace `apt-get install` with `dpkg -i, because the `ignore-depends` options seams only available for dpkg. And texstudio is now part of the official repo, no need for `add-apt repository` anymore

Answer (score -1):

First, see if TeXLive is installed: does the latex and pdflatex commands works?

If so, to install new packages:

If the downloaded package contains the .sty file, use it, if not run `latex <package>.ins` or `latex package.dtx` to generate the .sty file.

Then put the package.sty file in the /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/ directory, and run `sudo texhash` command to update TeXLive

Comment: I would not recommend to put files in directories otherwise maintained by the package manager. Instead i suggest to put the package related files in your own `texmf` tree. You can get the root path of this tree by invoking `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME`. Of course you can change `TEXMFHOME` to whatever you like.

Comment: Ok -- I have a TeXLive. How to downlad the files using bash, Corentin? What kind of files -- there are lots of them? In my question there was an exapmle. Example plese [xcoffins.sty]

Comment: How to get automatic update?

Comment: With the Ubuntu TL, there are no updates. Better to go for the TUG TL i stedet as mentioned else where. It does not provide automatic update, but it does provide an updater which one can run when ready. Automatic updates are not a good idea regarding LaTeX, as an update may end up breaking your document an hour before you need to hand it in.